# Dropbox Smart Sync 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, dropbox

I have upgraded Dropbox (Personal) to Dropbox (Personal Plus) which provides 2TB of (paid) cloud storage.

Clearly, with that amount of potential storage, syncing to the local drive will be an issue but Dropbox provides a solution with [Smart Sync](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/sync-uploads/smart-sync).

The current version of Dropbox from the Ubuntu Software Center installed is:

[image]

confirmed by Synaptic (although the app itself suggests v102.4.431 on 18.04 LTS) but this version does not provide the option to make use of Smart Sync, only Selective Sync. The difference between the two options is simply that with Selective, files/folders are not shown in the local synced Dropbox folder but with Smart Sync, a (best described as) token is placed in the local folder from which the file in the cloud can be opened making the whole process seamless.

In synaptic it shows that Python 3 version is available:

[image]

Will this version provide Smart Sync or is there another way of implementing this feature?

Further research shows that there is a [downloadable .deb](https://www.dropbox.com/install) for Ubuntu from Dropbox but it is not clear from the description whether this is a more up to date version than the one already installed (which will provide the functionability required). Is there wisdom in installing this deb package using [this](https://linuxconfig.org/install-deb-file-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) resource and what will happen to the existing installation?

> Note: these packages install an open-source helper application. The
> version of this application does not change as frequently as the main
> Dropbox application. These packages will always install the latest
> version of Dropbox for Linux.

Comment: Both `nautilus-dropbox` and `caja-dropbox` are wrappers for DropBox binary installers. You have to ask DropBox Linux team about implementation of this functionality.

Comment: I have a support ticket in to Dropbox but curious to know if anyone else has the same issue and how it was resolved - hence the question.

Comment: @User24601 would something like https://github.com/rianhunter/dbxfs work as an alternative?

Comment: @user2284570 Thanks for the suggestion. I resolved by by purchasing a Synology DS220j NAS mounted from fstab which is working fine for my current needs.

Comment: @User24601 except for needs of terabytes like mine this doesn t work. I d liked you to confirm it doesn t requires to cache the file first. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/147994/how-to-stream-a-file-to-dropbox

Comment: Getting Smart Sync on Linux would be great, but unfortunately it has not been made available yet. I suggest all who are interested in the feature go to [this page](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-ideas/When-will-Smart-Sync-work-on-linux/idi-p/262171) and upvote the suggestion. Dropbox is not guarenteed to listen, but it's about all we can do to get our voices heard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spite of information initially to the contrary when upgrading the Dropbox Personal (free) account to Personal (Plus) the Smart Sync feature is not available for Linux (and thus Ubuntu).

quote from Dropbox support:

> If I understand correctly, you would like to be able to use Smart Sync
> on your Linux device, is this correct?
>
> There are some things that it is not possible to use when using the
> Dropbox client on Linux.
>
> These are as follows:
>
> ```
> Camera Uploads
> Screenshot Uploads
> Two Accounts
> Custom Folder Icons for Shared Folders
> Smart Sync
> New Dropbox Desktop App
> ```
>
> I apologize for any inconvenience that this may cause.

In other ways Dropbox integrates extremely well with Ubuntu and it is a shame that the new and more able features are not available but hopefully, this question will assist any other user thinking along the lines of upgrading their account to Personal (Plus) or Professional.

To their credit, Dropbox have immediately refunded the upgrade fee without any question, returning the account to it's free status without any data loss and I do not hesitate in continuing to recommend the usefulness of Dropbox for cloud storage.